# NHibernate updating multiple transient objects exception: Error dehydrating property value for

Tags: nhibernate

I have a list of transient objects that I'd like to update, all from the same table.

```
IList<MyObject> objectsToUpdate = GetObjectsToUpdate();
using (var session = GetSession())
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    foreach (var obj in objectsToUpdate)
    {
        obj.Property = "new value";
        session.Update(obj);
    }
    transaction.Commit(); //exception thrown here
}
```

Exception message: Error dehydrating property value for MyObject.Property
Inner exception message: The length of the string value exceeds the length configured in the mapping/parameter.

The exception message didn't really make sense because there are no length configuration in the mapping, and the string is well within the range.

I was able to fix the problem by:

1) Calling session.Flush() after calling session.Update(obj)

```
IList<MyObject> objectsToUpdate = GetObjectsToUpdate();
using (var session = GetSession())
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    foreach (var obj in objectsToUpdate)
    {
        obj.Property = "new value";
        session.Update(obj);
        session.Flush();
    }
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

OR

2) Calling session.Merge(obj), modify its properties, then commit all at once.

```
IList<MyObject> objectsToUpdate = GetObjectsToUpdate();
using (var session = GetSession())
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    foreach (var obj in objectsToUpdate)
    {
        obj = session.Merge(obj);
        obj.Property = "new value";
    }
    transaction.Commit()
}
```

However, I'd like to understand why the exception was thrown when committing the transaction after multiple update calls without flushing after each update.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: What RDBMS? Which NHibernate version?

Comment: Sybase ASE 15.5 and NHibernate 3.3.2.4000

Answer (score 0):

the default length of string properties is 255 as seen when generating the tables from the mappings. Specify a bigger length for properties which can hold strings with length greater than 255.

Comment: Tables weren't generated from mappings and strings are well within the defined range.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be hitting the following issue:
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3355

It was reported for Sybase, but I'm unable to reproduce it. Read the comments on the issue report as well. What (file)version of their ADO.NET provider are you using?

Comment: Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient.dll file version 1.15.186.0  
I will take a look at that JIRA ticket.

Comment: Sounds like an older version than I used when testing, so it's consistent with my theory of this being a bug in earlier versions of their provider. Please see if you can try with an updated version and comment here or in the bug report.